# On implementing Material Search View, Textview is not shown at first launch

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm implementing searchview for my activity. It works well but I also want to show textview at first launch. But when i run app, then textview is not shown but only search menu item appears and when I search anything and click search button, then only textview appears and I can similarly search any item as before. But problem is on First launch the item in my xml don't appear and only toolbar with search menu item appears.  What is the cause of it?

Here is my code

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MaterialSearchView searchView;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        searchViewCode();
    }

    private void searchViewCode() {
        searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        searchView.setSuggestions(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.query_suggestions));
        searchView.setEllipsize(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSearchViewShown() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchViewClosed() {
            }
        });
    }    /*click alt+insert key */

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.material_search_menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView.setMenuItem(item);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (searchView.isSearchOpen()) {
            searchView.closeSearch();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

and my xml is

```html
<Linearlayout>
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/appcolor"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" />

<com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
android:id="@+id/search_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout> 
 <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/ev_title"
                    android:text="uis sed nisi arcu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    
                    </Linearlayout>
```

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should Constraint Layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/appcolor"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" />

        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/ev_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="uis sed nisi arcu"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_container" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```